# Is merely requesting app transparency permissions sufficient for ensuring google mobile ads are iOS14 compliant?

Tags: admob, ios14, google-mobile-ads, apptrackingtransparency

We have an app that shows Google banner, interstitial and reward ads. In iOS14 there are new requirements for [App Tracking](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/). This impacts Google Mobile ads as described here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14. We've implemented all their steps, including the final step:

```
func requestIDFA() {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
    // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
    loadAd()
})
```

}

Is this sufficient for iOS14 app tracking compliance as far as Google mobile ads are concerned?

The reason I ask is that with the European personalized ad consent we had to also include in the `GADRequest` (see: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent#forward-consent):

```
let status = PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus
let extras = GADExtras()
    
if status == .nonPersonalized || status == .unknown {
   extras.additionalParameters = ["npa": "1"]
}
```

Do we need to do something similar for iOS App Tracking? My gut feeling is "no" because otherwise they would have mentioned it specifically in their documentation, but want to be on the safe side.

Comment: We also need to provide privacy policy url which is mandatory and optional privacy choices url's https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/

Comment: So how are you handling this? The link to the EU consent is pointing to the legacy implementation. I am seeing that when I use the UMP framework and an EU user refuses to give consent no ads are displayed at all. I wish to fully ditch UMP and just show non personalised ads to EU users.